# Load Config file into Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I am attempting to build a tool using C# to modify the config files for our software.  The config files are in the following format:

SERVER_NAME       TestServer
SERVER_IP         127.0.0.1
SERVICE_NUMBER    4
SERVICE_ID        1 2 3 4

And so on.  Each line is prefaced with an identifier(Ex: SERVER_NAME), then the value.  I need the tool to load the value for each identifier into a separate text box.  When the user clicks save, it needs to write the updated information to the file.

I am entirely lost on how I should load the data into the text boxes, so if you could provide some help on that, I would appreciate it.

Writing it, I am assuming the easiest way, since all of the data will be loaded, is to erase the previous data, and write the new data to the file.  This I should be able to handle without a problem.  If there is a better way to do this, I am definitely willing to try.

I would greatly appreciate some pointers on how to get started with loading the data.

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFD.ShowDialog();
        openFD.Title = "Open a Config File...";
        openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:";
        openFD.FileName = "";
        openFD.Filter = "CONFIG|*.cfg";

        string selected_file = "";
        selected_file = openFD.FileName;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(selected_file))
        {
            string currLine;
            while ((currLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Matthew! I have put the start of my code below.  I have added a open file dialog, and set it up to load .CFG files.  I think I have the code correct for this, and I am then passing the file that is loaded to the StreamReader.

So my next question is, how can I take what is being read by the streamreader, read each identifier, and load the data into the correct text box, based off the identifier?  Each line has a unique identifier(Ex: SERVER_NAME) and then the value, after a tab.  How can I tell it to read the identifier SERVER_NAME, and load it into the text box named SERVER_NAME?

Comment: Get rid of the while-loop, it is of no use.  You'll need exactly four ReadLine() calls and each line needs to be parsed its own way.  Avoid having to write this kind of code by using XML.

Answer (score 0):

To read each line of the file you could do something like this:

```
// StreamReader is in System.IO
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("config file path here"))
{
    string currLine;
    while((currLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // currLine will have the current line value as a string
        // You can then manipulate it any way you like
        // Or store it in an array or List<>
    }
}
```

If you need help with adding items into a textbox, just ask.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I posted my code on my first post.  Can't figure out how to post responses with code.  The code there is what I've been able to come up with so far.